# Como instalar Materialize para que funcione con Vue.js en Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, materialize

actualmente trabajo con Laravel, Vue.js y Boostrap y todo funciona.
Pero cuando quiero usar Materialize, Vue.js deja de funcionar, pues Vue.js viene por defecto para trabajar con Boostrap y no sé que tengo que hacer.

Gracias de antemano.

El archivo `boostrap.js` que se instala con Vue.

```
window._ = require('lodash');
window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;

/**
 * We'll load jQuery and the Bootstrap jQuery plugin which provides support
 * for JavaScript based Bootstrap features such as modals and tabs. This
 * code may be modified to fit the specific needs of your application.
 */

try {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
} catch (e) {}

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Next we will register the CSRF Token as a common header with Axios so that
 * all outgoing HTTP requests automatically have it attached. This is just
 * a simple convenience so we don't have to attach every token manually.
 */

let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]');

if (token) {
    window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;
} else {
    console.error('CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token');
}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso checa el [tour]; tu pregunta tiene problemas de formato y puede terminar cerrada

Comment: Vue.js no viene por defecto para trabajar con nada. Tal vez tengas otra libreria que haga eso, pero vue.js no.

Comment: Quieres usar 2 librerías de CSS en el mismo proyecto? Seguro que te va a dar problemas. Intenta decidir cual de las 2 quieres usar, bootstrap o materializecss.